# Which port is used by Delphi RemoteDebugger?

Tags: delphi

I want to start a remote dbg session and the router on the remove computer is blocking the debugger. I can do port forwarding but I cannot find which port it is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved :)

rmtdbg.exe [-listen [hostname:]port]

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Installing,_Starting,_and_Stopping_the_Remote_Debug_Server) covers this in some detail.

> **To install and start the remote debug server**
>
> 1. If RAD Studio is installed on the remote computer, skip to step 3. In this case, the remote debug server (rmtdbg.exe) is already
>      available, by default, at C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD
>      Studio\6.0\Bin.
> 2. Follow the directions for Installing a Debugger on a Remote Machine.
> 3. On the remote computer, run rmtdbg<nnn>.exe using the following syntax:
>
>    ```
>    rmtdbg<nnn>.exe [-listen [hostname:]port]
>    ```
>
>    where:
>
>    - `<nnn>` is the version number associated with the current release.
>    - `hostname` is an optional host name or TCP/IP address for binding to a particular host, for example, somehost or 127.0.0.1. If you specify
>        hostname, you must also specify `:port`.
>    - `port` is an optional (required if hostname is specified) port number or standard protocol name, for example, 8000 or ftp. If omitted, 64447
>        is used as the port number.

Comment: That's only half of the story. When IDE connects to remote debugger, debugger spawns child process on random port. So you need a firewall, that is able to allow connections on per process basis. If you need to break through a separate router, then you will need to setup VPN server on this router. And then start VPN connection on computer with IDE, before debugging.